# Android Studio - How to run a method constantly?

Tags: java, android

So here is my main and only activity's code:

```
package com.batteryapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView batterytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.battery_text);
        batterytext.setText("test");

    }
    private static Thread myThread; //this is the code I got from the tutorial
    private static boolean ThreadsRunning;
    public void Test1(MainActivity activity)
    {
        final MainActivity fActivity = activity;
        ThreadsRunning = true;
        myThread = new Thread(){

            public void run()
            {
                int counter = 0;
                while (ThreadsRunning)
                {
                    TextView batterytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.battery_text);
                    String batteryLevelText = Integer.toString(counter);
                    batterytext.setText(counter); //wanted to first test with a counter that counts up every second
                    counter+=1;
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ex)
                    {
                        Log.e("TAG", "Thread Sleep Error", ex);
                    }
                    /*TextView batterytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.battery_text);
                    float batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel();
                    String batteryLevelText = Float.toString(batteryLevel);
                    batterytext.setText(batteryLevelText);
                    */
                }
            }
        };

        myThread.start();
        //ThreadsRunning = false; #this stops the thread
    }

    public float getBatteryLevel() {
        Intent batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        int level = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

        // Error checking that probably isn't needed but I added just in case.
        if (level == -1 || scale == -1) {
            return 50.0f;
        }

        return ((float) level / (float) scale) * 100.0f;
    }


}
```

Only thing I don't know how to do is to actually call the tutorial code and make it run in the background!
I followed a tutorial on YouTube in an attempt to get the following code to run constantly in the background without freezing the entire phone:

```
TextView batterytext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.battery_text);
float batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel();
String batteryLevelText = Float.toString(batteryLevel);
batterytext.setText(batteryLevelText);
```

I tried that in a while statement in the MainActivity class, but it merely froze the UI and I had to restart my phone. I am fairly new at Java (only know Python), but I wanted to start learning it to build simple Android apps.

What I'm basically trying to do is display an up-to-date battery level in a TextView, which works perfectly fine if I put those four lines in the main class, but then it only runs it once. It does not update when the battery percentage changes.

I wanted to run it in the background so that I can do other stuff while it's constantly updating.

I searched everywhere and found some examples but have no idea how to implement them into my code. If anyone could offer some help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read battery status dont do it in thread or Main. In android there is a broadcast named `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` that fires a event whenever there is some change in battery status. Register the battery receiver using following code

```
this.registerReceiver(this.receiver, 
        new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

And your broadcast listener should be -

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

    int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
    Log.e("test", String.valueOf(level) + "%");

     }
};
```

Unregister receiver using

```
this.unregisterReceiver(this.receiver);
```

Comment: You have to understand I am completely new to Java and don't know what registering is, or where to even put this and how to use it. Do I put this all in the MainActivity class that extends AppCompatActivity and then call it from onCreate?

Comment: Android fires system events whenever there is needed one. Same is for battery status. Please go through http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html for more information.
What you tried in your above code is not the correct way to do it!

Comment: Okay, I think I got it to work!...maybe... Edit: It works! Thanks Neji!